# Angular 2 not passing JSESSIONID on subsequent requests

Tags: javascript, angular, http, cookies, jsessionid

Using Angular 6.1.3.

The login request is sending the JSESSIONID cookie on the response.  However, any subsequent request is not including this cookie.  In searching around most mentioned the use of use of withCredentials: true.  However I am using this and still not successful.  Have tried on both Chrome and Firefox.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

At one time another cookie was present and withCredentials was causing THAT cookie to be included, but NOT JSESSIONID.  Very frustrating.

I have also tried to access the JSESSIONID manually to include it myself even though that should not be required. However even "Observe: 'response'" is not allowing me to see the JSESSIONID cookie's value.  So if I have to go this route, please advise on how to access this.

Is there any restriction to the type of request being sent?  Even though I tried a GET without success, when the answer is supplied, will it work with any type of subsequent request (i.e. POST, PUT, PATCH)?

Login reqeust:

```js
        const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams().set('token.name', username).append('token.value', password);
        const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        return this.httpClient
            .post<any>(this.loginUrl, params, { headers: headers, params: params,  withCredentials: true })
            .map(adjudicator  => {
    return adjudicator.adjudicator as Adjudicator;
   })
            .catch(this.errorHelperService.handleError);
```

[Login Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiGQy.jpg)

[login Response Cookie tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIup8.jpg)

Subsequent Request:

```js
        // test request
        const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this.httpClient
            .get<any>(this.configService.getManagerUrl()+'1/bada8257-e7d9-45d3-a8a1-83a67f863260',  { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
            .map(response  => {
                return response.match as Match;
            })
            .catch(this.errorHelperService.handleError);
```

[Subsequent Test Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU6KH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The cookie has the "secure" directive and the site you are trying to access is not secure.

> A secure cookie is only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies